# Kafka Consumer Offsets expiration

Tags: apache-kafka

I have this scenario.

A kafka broker with *offsets.retention.minutes* set to 1440 (1 day)
1 consumer **C**, consuming from topic **T**
Topic **T** has *1 week retention*.

Oldest data on topic **T** is from *1 day ago*.

Topic **T** will receive no more data from now on.

What happen is consumer **C** has consumed data from topic **T** *1 day ago*, then, today, its offsets expire and it consumes again data from topic **T** from the beginning.

So i update *offsets.retention.minutes* and i restart the broker, but offsets for consumer **C** and topic **T** remain with expire date set to "tomorrow", when data will be consumed again from the beginning.

How can i avoid this?

Basically, how can i update the expiration date of the offsets?
I have thought to push a fake message to the topic in order to force the update of the offset but i think it's gross and there must be a more elegant way to do it

Comment: If I understand the question you have set this property value https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset value to from beginning and you dont want to process from beginning upon restarting consumer again?